# get_absolute_url is not working

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am practicing with the github source code shown below, but I'm stuck getting the `get_absolute_url` method to work. Not able to access `svariable.html`. It's always redirecting to the `base.html`. Any help would be much appreciated. Please find below the code with little change:

https://github.com/GeoffMahugu/Django-Ecommerce

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', blank=True)
    default_category = models.ForeignKey('Category', related_name='default_category', null=True, blank=True,
                                         on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    default_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_upload_to_prod, blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('Products:SingleProduct', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

**views.py**

```
def SingleProduct(request, pk):
    objects = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=pk)
    vari = Variation.objects.filter(product=objects)
    obj_cat = objects.default_category
    obj_prod = Product.objects.filter(default_category=obj_cat).exclude(pk=objects.pk).order_by('-pk')[:3]
    title = '%s' % (objects.title)
    cart_id = request.session.get('cart_id')
    object = get_object_or_404(Cart, pk=cart_id)
    cart_count = object.cartitem_set.count()
    cart_items = object.cartitem_set.all()
    context = {
        'vari': vari,
        'title': title,
        'objects': objects,
        'obj_prod': obj_prod,
        'cart_count': cart_count,
        'cart_items': cart_items
    }
    template = 'svariable.html'
    return render(request, template, context)

def Home(request):
    request.session.set_expiry(0)
    title = 'Welcome to E-shop Germany'
    products = Product.objects.all().order_by('?')
    featured = Product.objects.filter(featured=True).order_by('?')[0:]
    prod_no = products.count()
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    cart_id = request.session.get('cart_id')
    if cart_id == None:
        cart = Cart()
        cart.save()
        cart_id = cart.id
        request.session['cart_id'] = cart_id
    cart = Cart.objects.get(pk=cart_id)
    cart_count = cart.cartitem_set.count()
    cart_items = cart.cartitem_set.all()
    context = {
        'title': title,
        'products': products,
        'featured': featured,
        'prod_no': prod_no,
        'categories': categories,
        'cart': cart,
        'cart_count': cart_count,
        'cart_items': cart_items
    }
    return render(request, 'base.html', context)
```

root **urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^Products/', include('products.urls',namespace='Products' )),
    url(r'^Carts/', include('carts.urls', namespace='Carts' )),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls), 
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url('',Home, name = 'Home'),    
    url(r'^home/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', SingleProduct , name='SingleProduct'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', SingleCategory, name='SingleCategory'),
]
```

Comment: You should show your URLs.

Comment: I added the urls now.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your URLs: the pattern for Home matches every path.  You need to anchor at the start and end.

```
url('^$', Home, name='Home')
```